# Spark python MLlib Random Forest out of memory error

Tags: python, apache-spark, random-forest, apache-spark-mllib

I am running spark 1.2.1 to train a random forest. I have a master and a worker node setup on AWS EC2 with total 96GB of memory allocated to spark. I played with various parallelism values (32, 64, 6400) and I keep getting the same error. According to the spark UI, my RDD is 277KB, 100% cached in memory, which should be tiny. My spark context is as follows:

```
spark.executor.memory   100000m
spark.driver.memory 90000m
spark.driver.maxResultSize 0
spark.storage.memoryFraction 0.6
spark.default.parallelism 6400
spark.eventLog.enabled true
spark.executor.extraLibraryPath /root/ephemeral-hdfs/lib/native/
spark.executor.extraClassPath   /root/ephemeral-hdfs/conf

# for spark version < 1.4.0
spark.tachyonStore.url tachyon://10.0.29.29:19998
# for spark version >= 1.4.0
spark.externalBlockStore.url tachyon://10.0.29.29:19998
```

The error is as follows:

```
15/09/16 21:32:38 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 6397.0 in stage 31.0 (TID 51197) in 4 ms on 10.0.29.186 (6398/6400)
15/09/16 21:32:38 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 6398.0 in stage 31.0 (TID 51198) in 4 ms on 10.0.29.186 (6399/6400)
15/09/16 21:32:38 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 6399.0 in stage 31.0 (TID 51199) in 4 ms on 10.0.29.186 (6400/6400)
15/09/16 21:32:38 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 31.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
15/09/16 21:32:38 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ResultStage 31 (collect at DecisionTree.scala:977) finished in 1.843 s
15/09/16 21:32:38 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 31 finished: collect at DecisionTree.scala:977, took 1.889432 s
15/09/16 21:32:46 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_32_piece0 on 10.0.29.44:60955 in memory (size: 3.9 KB, free: 45.5 GB)
15/09/16 21:32:46 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_32_piece0 on 10.0.29.186:43335 in memory (size: 3.9 KB, free: 50.5 GB)
15/09/16 21:34:24 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(46872) called with curMem=0, maxMem=48837427200
15/09/16 21:34:24 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_33 stored as values in memory (estimated size 45.8 KB, free 45.5 GB)
15/09/16 21:34:24 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(46927) called with curMem=46872, maxMem=48837427200
15/09/16 21:34:24 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_33_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 45.8 KB, free 45.5 GB)
15/09/16 21:34:24 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_33_piece0 in memory on 10.0.29.44:60955 (size: 45.8 KB, free: 45.5 GB)
15/09/16 21:34:24 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 33 from broadcast at DecisionTree.scala:592
15/09/16 21:35:43 INFO rdd.MapPartitionsRDD: Removing RDD 24 from persistence list
15/09/16 21:35:43 INFO storage.BlockManager: Removing RDD 24
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "random_forest_spark.py", line 142, in trainModel
    impurity='gini', maxDepth=4, maxBins=32)
  File "/root/spark/python/pyspark/mllib/tree.py", line 352, in trainClassifier
    maxDepth, maxBins, seed)
  File "/root/spark/python/pyspark/mllib/tree.py", line 270, in _train
    maxDepth, maxBins, seed)
  File "/root/spark/python/pyspark/mllib/common.py", line 128, in callMLlibFunc
    return callJavaFunc(sc, api, *args)
  File "/root/spark/python/pyspark/mllib/common.py", line 121, in callJavaFunc
    return _java2py(sc, func(*args))
  File "/root/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__
  File "/root/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o169.trainRandomForestModel.
: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.hugeCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:123)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:117)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1876)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1785)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1188)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:44)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:312)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:305)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1891)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1.apply(RDD.scala:683)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1.apply(RDD.scala:682)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:148)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:286)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitions(RDD.scala:682)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.DecisionTree$.findBestSplits(DecisionTree.scala:613)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.RandomForest.run(RandomForest.scala:235)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.RandomForest$.trainClassifier(RandomForest.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.api.python.PythonMLLibAPI.trainRandomForestModel(PythonMLLibAPI.scala:666)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My data is a LabeledPoint type RDD and my training code is fairly straight forward:

```
 (trainingData, testData) = data.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])
    model = RandomForest.trainClassifier(trainingData, numClasses=2, categoricalFeaturesInfo={},
                                     numTrees=3, featureSubsetStrategy="auto",
                                     impurity='gini', maxDepth=4, maxBins=32)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my Tachyon server IP was incorrect. Configuring the correct Tachyon server IP solved my problem.

Comment: A bit late, but in case you remember, was it only the server IP you changed?Not the server itself? I am getting the same error and I have a spark driver with 235g and 3 worker nodes(1 executor each with 4 cores and 115g).